# The meaning of a sentence with いっちょ in this context

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage

There is a sentence which I don't understand much, describing a prince who is about to become the new king. Hope someone can explain its correct meaning to me.

**Context:**

Previously, when a coup broke out in the kingdom, this prince didn't do anything to help and instead MC's party had neutralized the culprits behind the coup, therefore saving the kingdom and its people.

After a while, MC's group suddenly received an invitation from the royal court to a big party inside the royal palace (but they don't understand why the royal court did this since the previous King had been assassinated, and there are still lot of problems inside the Royal Court -- basically there's almost nothing to be happy about and hold a party).

One member from MC's party said this about the coward prince : 「いっちょ腑抜け面を見に行こうじゃないの」 (my guess but not sure: "Let's go to see his coward face shall we ?" because the "いっちょ/iccho/ ichhou ? part")

**Full conversation:**

A「王子ねぇ……まぁ、グラムやソウルドラゴンの時の対応を見る限り、腑抜けた奴なんでしょうね」

A「結局王宮に引きこもって、動こうとしなかったもんね」

A「前の王のギルバート王は、英傑と言われたけど……まぁその子どもが腑抜けっていうのは、ままあることよね」

**A「いっちょ腑抜け面を見に行こうじゃないの」**

B「いいけど、今みたいな台詞を本人の目の前で言うのは勘弁してよ。そのまま打ち首になりたくない」

Answer (score 2):

[いっちょ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1%E3%82%87/#jn-276779) is a form of [一丁](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%B8%80%E4%B8%81/#jn-13492):

> ［名］
> ４ 勝負事などの一回。ひと勝負。「もう―やろう」
>
> ［副］《4から》物事を始めるときに言う語。ひとつ思いきって。それでは。さあ。「―とりかかるか」

It is an interjection for starting something. Practically it is correct to interpret it as *let's go see his coward face*.

Comment: at first i think this character is using a dialect いっちょ >> like いっしょに (isshoni/ go together)